# C# Xaml How to get listbox selected item textbox value

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing windows phone 8.1 app, and I need to get value of textboxes named:"time_tb" and "task_text_tb", that are in my selected item. This is my Xaml code:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="list" ItemsSource="{Binding tasks}" Background="White" Margin="-1,50,-1,63">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <Grid Margin="1" Height="76" Tapped="Grid_Tapped" Width="389">

                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="83*" />

                        <ColumnDefinition Width="307*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="time_tb" Margin="0,15,276,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding time}" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderBrush="#FF49B7DC" Width="83" Height="45" FontSize="18.667" Foreground="{x:Null}" Background="White" FontFamily="Segoe UI Emoji" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="1">

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />

                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="task_text_tb" Margin="63,14,10,39.833" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding wht}"  FontSize="16"  SelectionHighlightColor="#FF1455B3" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <StackPanel Height="100" Width="100"/>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel, keep a property for the SelectedItem (binded to your list selectedItem) and 2 property for the textboxes of the current selected item that you will update when SelectedItem is changed. Then bind those 2 properties to where you want to show the values.

You may have to do some magic to find the actual selected item, because i think selected item only returns an index or something...

Hope this helps